# optimize Powershell RegEx match

Tags: regex, powershell

I'd like to have a RegEx in Powershell which matches following expressions:

- MusMax / musmax
- MusMax1 / musmax1

But it should not match with:

- tMusMax / tmusmax
- tMusMax1 / tmusmax1
- itMusMax / itmusmax
- itMusMax1 / itmusmax1

The code that I have until now is following:

```
((?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d).{6,7})
```

My Problem is that this RegEx only matches to the expressions with a digit in the last place, but the digit is optional so it should not match only these.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: add a `?` after the digit (`\d`)

Comment: You haven't defined what your regex should match very well. Can you write one sentence of plain English for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be as simple as:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{6}\d?\b
```

(My interpretation of your samples was "Whole words of six ASCII characters that end in an optional additional digit.")

Comment: Thank Tomalak for the quick answer! Your Interpretation was right and so was your RegEx.